# Install `libudunits2-dev` on Amazon Linux 2

Tags: r, linux, amazon-linux-2

I'm working in an Amazon-Linux-2 environment and would like to install the R-package `"sf"` which depends on the `libudunits2-dev` system library. I get the error message:

```
Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try installing:
    * deb: libudunits2-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
    * rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
    * brew: udunits (OSX)
  If udunits2 is already installed in a non-standard location, use:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'
  if the library was not found, and/or:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values.
  You can alternatively set UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS manually.
```

udunits2 cannot be installed with `sudo yum install libudunits2-dev` or `libunits2-devel`. I attempted installing and using `epel` but that also does not contain this library.

I installed `udunits2` from source, and it can find the library but there is still an error. I am unsure how to build a `dev` version of this library

```
wget ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/udunits/udunits-2.2.28.tar.gz &&\
  tar -xvzf udunits-2.2.28.tar.gz; rm udunits-2.2.28.tar.gz &&\
  cd udunits-2.2.28 &&\
  ./configure -prefix=/usr/local &&\
  make install &&\
  cd .. && rm -rf udunits-2.2.28
```

Current error message:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'units' in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/lib64/R/library/00LOCK-units/00new/units/libs/units.so':
  libudunits2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/units'
ERROR: dependency 'units' is not available for package 'sf'
```

Edit ---------------------------

Thanks Knud Larsen for correcting the epel-package name. It looks like the installation is a bit involved but here is what I've figured out.

The [sf package](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/) dependencies are `libudunits2-dev libgdal-dev libgeos-dev libproj-dev`. Which for amazon-linux-2 needs epel and to built from source. (note: epel gdal is version 1 and not compatible).

```
# Add epel repository
sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel

# install udunits2
yum install -y udunits2-devel

# install proj/gdal dependency
yum install -y gcc-c++ cpp sqlite-devel libtiff cmake3

# build/install proj
wget https://download.osgeo.org/proj/proj-6.1.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf proj-6.1.1.tar.gz
cd proj-6.1.1
./configure
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -rf proj-6.1.1*

# build/install gdal
wget https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/releases/download/v3.2.1/gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz
tar -xvf gdal-3.2.1.tar.gz
cd gdal-3.2.1
./configure --with-proj=/usr/local --with-python
sudo make
sudo make install
cd ..
rm -rf gdal-3.2.1*
```

Comment: The EPEL package name is `udunits2-devel` https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/u/ .......... Ref. https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/

Comment: The package DESCRIPTION file does not indicate such a requirement. I'm guessing that you have not given us the entire console output but rather only the part that you _thought_ was needed.

Comment: You're right IRTFM, the dependency is actually on another package which SF depends on called `units`.