# R: How can I install terra on Amazon Linux 2?

Tags: r, redhat, terra

I'm having some trouble running `install.packages("terra")` on Amazon Linux 2 with R 4.0.2 on an EC2. The output is the following:

```
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available for linking:... yes
checking GDAL: checking whether PROJ is available fur running:... ./gdal_proj: error while loading shared libraries: libgdal.so.28: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
no
configure: error: OGRCoordinateTransformation() does not return a coord.trans: PROJ not available?
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'terra'
* removing '/usr/lib64/R/library/terra'

The downloaded source packages are in
    '/tmp/RtmplRJO0R/downloaded_packages'
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
```

My understanding is that terra depends on compiled packages GDAL and PROJ. The best guide I found to install is [this one](https://gist.github.com/abelcallejo/e75eb93d73db6f163b076d0232fc7d7e). Unfortunately I still get the above error even though GDAL and PROJ are installed. Before this guide I tried using [yum to install proj](https://proj.org/install.html), but yum would install proj 4.8.0 which is too old to meet the minimum requirements for GDAL. Has anyone successfully installed terra on Amazon Linux 2?

Comment: perhaps some helpful ideas here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69247571/install-libudunits2-dev-on-amazon-linux-2